# Zurb foundation nested reveal modal closes all pop up when one is closed

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using zurb foundation framework.I nested one reveal modal inside the main one. WHen I close the second modal, the main one also closes. I guess this is a common way on how foundation's nested modals work as I checked the documentation and found the same problem in their website.

Is there anyway I could change this default function. WHere only reveal modal with related id would close?

Currently:

WHen this clicked:

```
<a data-reveal-id="myModal_signupSubject" data-reveal><span  class="menuBox">Tutor Sign Up</span></a>
```

This opens:

```
 <section id="myModal_signupSubject" class="reveal-modal text-center" data-reveal>
     <span class="titleOrange">Tutor Signup</span><br/>
     Step 1: Select Subjects and
     Set <span class="orange">Hourly </span>Prices 

     <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="insertSub">&times;</a>//closes this current reveal modal
      <a data-reveal-id="myModal_signup" data-reveal><input type="button" id="browse" value="Browse Subjects"></a>//invokes another reveal modal
   </section>
```

WHen the link in the above modal is clicked the following modal opens:

```
<section id="myModal_signup" class="reveal-modal text-center" data-reveal>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" id="closeNested">&times;</a>//this closes the current modal
 <span class="titleSpecial">Tutor Sign Up</span><br/>
 Step 1: Select Subjects and Set <span class="orange">Hourly</span> Prices<br/>
<a data-reveal-id="myModal_signupSubjects" data-reveal><span  id="searchLink"> <input type="button" id="browse" value="Browse Subjects"></span>
```

I tried providing ID for each modal and close them specifically but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).foundation();
  $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal#closeNested').click(function(){
  $('#myModal_signupSubject').foundation('reveal', 'close');
});

$(document).foundation();
  $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal#insertSub').click(function(){
  $('#myModal_signupSubject').foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

I also found that, whenever the nested reveal modal link is clicked, automatically the first modal closes thus the second opens.

How to:

1) Make the first modal reopens automatically when the second modal closed?

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/xk2rbp9s/6/ ?

Answer (score 0):

this should be possible by adding the data-reveal-id to the close button of the 2nd modal:

```
<a class="close-reveal-modal" href="#" data-reveal-id="id-of-first-modal">Close only 2nd modal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now add `data-multiple-opened="true"` to the `data-reveal` elements:

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.motion.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.triggers.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.keyboard.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.3/js/plugins/foundation.reveal.min.js"></script>
<!-- This demo uses flex grid but you can use float grid too -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <h2>Reveal - Nested Modal</h2>
    <p>It's possible for modals to open other modals. Create a second modal with a unique ID, and then add a click trigger with <code>data-open</code> inside the first modal.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <p><a data-open="exampleModal2">Click me for a modal</a></p>

    <!-- This is the first modal -->
    <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal2" data-reveal data-multiple-opened="true">
      <h1>Awesome!</h1>
      <p class="lead">I have another modal inside of me!</p>
      <a class="button" data-open="exampleModal3">Click me for another modal!</a>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the nested modal -->
    <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal3" data-reveal data-multiple-opened="true">
      <h2>ANOTHER MODAL!!!</h2>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```